# Split column value in SQL and show in next line

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ID   NAME     TYPE
1    ABC      1,2,3,4
2    PQR      2,3,5 
3    XYZ      1,4
4    TCS      3,1
5    PPP      2,3
```

I want output like this

```
ID   NAME     TYPE
1    ABC      1
              2
              3
              4
2    pqr      2
              3
              5
```

and so on

Comment: So you just want to remove the commas? If so, use the REPLACE function. However, I feel I must be missing something.

Comment: remove comma and show value in next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic challenges with this; splitting the comma separated list of values and then only displaying the first instance of ID and NAME. There may be more efficient or elegant ways to achieve this. However, I have chosen a brute force approach using a cursor. Here you go.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results;

CREATE TABLE #Temp (
  ID INT
, NAME CHAR(3)
, TYPE VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #Results (
  ID VARCHAR(3)
, NAME CHAR(3)
, TYPE VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT  INTO #Temp (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (1, 'ABC', '1,2,3,4')
INSERT  INTO #Temp (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (2, 'PQR', '2,3,5')
INSERT  INTO #Temp (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (3, 'XYZ', '1,4')
INSERT  INTO #Temp (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (4, 'TCS', '3,1')
INSERT  INTO #Temp (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (5, 'PPP', '2,3')

DECLARE @First BIT
DECLARE @ValueList VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100)

/* declare cursor variables */
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @NAME CHAR(3)
DECLARE @TYPE VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT * FROM #Temp

OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ID, @NAME, @TYPE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @ValueList = @TYPE + ','
    SET @pos = 0
    SET @len = 0
    SET @First = 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ValueList, @pos + 1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @ValueList, @pos + 1) - @pos
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@ValueList, @pos, @len)
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ValueList, @pos + @len) + 1

        IF (@First = 1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (@ID, @NAME, @value)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES ('', '', @value)
        END
        SET @First = 0
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ID, @NAME, @TYPE
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor

SELECT * FROM #Results
```

Enjoy,

Noel